# jQuery UI draggable - scroll vertical and horizontal issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Technologies: html, css, javascript, jquery and jquery ui.

Fiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7q2G/5/   **(hit the run button)**

Hi, I have one div (parent div) and 3 lists (ul) inside of parent div.
The 3 lists are identical (css and html elements)
With jquery ui I make the list sortable and connected (you can sort elements between lists)

The html is

```
<div class="parent">
<ul  class="list l1">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
list2.... 
list3....
</div>
```

The parent div has the next css:

```
width: 400px;
border: 1px red solid;
height: 300px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
```

And the list element has the next css:

```
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid blue;
height: 160px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

And the js is:

```
$( ".l1, .l2, .l3 ").sortable({
    connectWith: ".list"
}).disableSelection();
```

**The problem:**
The scroll, when I take an element from list one and I want to put inside list 3 the scroll from parent div (red border) does not work (horizontal issue).

And also, when I take an element from list one and I want to put at the end of list 2 the scroll from list 2 does not work (vertical issue).

Could someone help me with these issues ?

Thanks a lot.

Regards.

Comment: In other words, you want it to autoscroll while dragging?

Comment: It looks like you'd have to write a custom method to track the position of the element in relation to the other lists. I would recommend using the `over` event; this is pretty much equivalent to the `drag` event for `draggable` objects.

Comment: This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7q2G/10/) isn't perfect, but it might give you an idea of a direction to go in.

Comment: Thanks, it is a good example, I will try to implement something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I made a concept that might help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/srpoder/9tLBd/29/

```
# Stackoverflow required me to add some code, so I did.
```

Comment: This is a complete solution.
Thank you